# opencv-python : drawMatchesKnn() always return NULL

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, feature-detection

I want to make a simple project about logo detecting. So I tried to follow OpenCV-Python tutorial about feature detection. [OpenCV: Feature Matching](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dc/dc3/tutorial_py_matcher.html)

I wrote my code like below.

```
ratio = 0.8
logo = cv.imread("T01/CocaCola_logo2.png", cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
img = cv.imread("T01/CocaCola.png", cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

orb = cv.ORB_create()
kp_logo, des_logo = orb.detectAndCompute(logo, None)
kp_img, des_img = orb.detectAndCompute(img, None)

FLANN_INDEX_LSH = 6
index_params = dict(algorithm=FLANN_INDEX_LSH,
                    table_number=6,
                    key_size=12,
                    multi_probe_level=1)
search_params = dict(checks=50)
flann = cv.FlannBasedMatcher(index_params, search_params)
match_flann = flann.knnMatch(des_logo, des_img, k=2)

good = []
for p, q in match_flann:
    if p.distance > q.distance*ratio:
        good.append(p)

try:
    img_match = np.empty((max(logo.shape[0], img.shape[0]), logo.shape[1] + img.shape[1], 3), dtype=np.uint8)
    cv.drawMatchesKnn(logo, kp_logo, img, kp_img, good,
                      outImg=img_match, matchColor=None, singlePointColor=(255, 255, 255), flags=2)
    cv.imshow("flann matching", img_match)
    cv.waitKey(0)
except:
    print("...")
```

This code does not work properly. Process always got handled by error with drawMatchesKnn(). Before I add try-except to that function, process made a system error : *SystemError:  returned NULL without setting an error*

What is the cause of the problem? I tried to search for a long time but it's not easy to me.

---

stack trace : 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/choib/Desktop/openCVtest3/T01_ORBtest.py", line 73, in 
    cv.drawMatchesKnn(logo, kp_logo, img, kp_img, good, outImg=img_match, matchColor=None, singlePointColor=(255, 255, 255), flags=2)
    SystemError:  returned NULL without setting an error

Comment: can you provide the stack trace? have you tried with the minimum params required, like: `img_match = cv.drawMatchesKnn(logo, kp_logo, img, kp_img, good, flags=2) ` does it give you also error?

Comment: @api55 I add stack trace in question. And also I changed the function like : `img_match = cv.drawMatchesKnn(logo, kp_logo, img, kp_img, good, outImg=None, flags=2)` (if outImg is not mentioned, it cause type error.) But it has same error as I wrote in question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I misunderstood about drawMatches() and drawMatchesKnn(). [reference](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/features2d/doc/drawing_function_of_keypoints_and_matches.html)

drawMatchesKnn() needs to get vector which is composed by vectors of DMatch as matches1to2. So in my case I fixed the code like below.

case 1: to use properly

```
img_match = np.empty((max(logo.shape[0], img.shape[0]), logo.shape[1] + img.shape[1], 3), dtype=np.uint8)
cv.drawMatches(logo, kp_logo, img, kp_img, good_flann,
               outImg=img_match, matchColor=None, singlePointColor=(255, 255, 255), flags=2)
cv.imshow("flann matching", img_match)
cv.waitKey(0)
```

case 2: to use drawMatchesKnn()

```
img_match = np.empty((max(logo.shape[0], img.shape[0]), logo.shape[1] + img.shape[1], 3), dtype=np.uint8)
cv.drawMatchesKnn(logo, kp_logo, img, kp_img, match_flann,
                  outImg=img_match, matchColor=None, singlePointColor=(255, 255, 255), flags=2)
cv.imshow("flann matching", img_match)
cv.waitKey(0)
```

In those codes, good_flann is just vector of DMatch. And match_flann is vector of vector. So process doesn't have any problem with those parts.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error because I was trying to draw matches with `drawMatchesKnn` by passing to it a list of `DMatch` objects. However, `drawMatchesKnn` requires a list of lists, each of which contains `DMatch` objects.